# JTable with different JComboBox-es for each row

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jcombobox

I created `JTable` that contains information about employees. In this JTable I added the column called "Qualifications". This column is represented by `JComboBox` (different content at each row). For instance:

```
Row 1 |  JComboBox(){"Programmer","Web"}
Row 2 |  JComboBox(){"Writer","Editor"}
```

The `JComboBox` content is taken from the `List<String> employees[row].getQualification()`.

The problem is that the selected item in Row 1 and Row 2 is "Programmer", however "Programmer" should not appear in Row 2. Only when I click on `JComboBox`, the correct list appears, i.e. Row 2 - {"Writer","Editor"}.

```
    TableColumn column = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(5);
    column.setCellRenderer(getRenderer());

    private TableCellRenderer getRenderer() {
    return new TableCellRenderer() {

        private JComboBox<String> box = new JComboBox<String>();
        @Override
        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value,
                boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {            
            for (String q : employees[row].getQualification())
                box.addItem(q);
            box.setBackground(isSelected ? table.getSelectionBackground() : table.getBackground());
            box.setForeground(isSelected ? table.getSelectionForeground() : table.getForeground());
            return box;
           }
        };
    }
```

Comment: I'm sure that you joking here, one specific example by ignoring rulles here, non_posting SSCCE/MCVE/MCTRE, second by ignoring official Oracle tutorial, etc... (sure someone will answering your question as always)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Override the `getCellEditor()` method of the `JTable`. Something like:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;

public class TableComboBoxByRow extends JPanel
{
    List<TableCellEditor> editors = new ArrayList<TableCellEditor>(3);

    public TableComboBoxByRow()
    {
        setLayout( new BorderLayout() );

        // Create the editors to be used for each row

        String[] items1 = { "Red", "Blue", "Green" };
        JComboBox<String> comboBox1 = new JComboBox<String>( items1 );
        DefaultCellEditor dce1 = new DefaultCellEditor( comboBox1 );
        editors.add( dce1 );

        String[] items2 = { "Circle", "Square", "Triangle" };
        JComboBox<String> comboBox2 = new JComboBox<String>( items2 );
        DefaultCellEditor dce2 = new DefaultCellEditor( comboBox2 );
        editors.add( dce2 );

        String[] items3 = { "Apple", "Orange", "Banana" };
        JComboBox<String> comboBox3 = new JComboBox<String>( items3 );
        DefaultCellEditor dce3 = new DefaultCellEditor( comboBox3 );
        editors.add( dce3 );

        //  Create the table with default data

        Object[][] data =
        {
            {"Color", "Red"},
            {"Shape", "Square"},
            {"Fruit", "Banana"},
            {"Plain", "Text"}
        };
        String[] columnNames = {"Type","Value"};
        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames);
        JTable table = new JTable(model)
        {
            //  Determine editor to be used by row
            public TableCellEditor getCellEditor(int row, int column)
            {
                int modelColumn = convertColumnIndexToModel( column );

                if (modelColumn == 1 && row < 3)
                    return editors.get(row);
                else
                    return super.getCellEditor(row, column);
            }
        };

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane( table );
        add( scrollPane );
    }

    private static void createAndShowUI()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Table Combo Box by Row");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add( new TableComboBoxByRow() );
        frame.setSize(200, 200);
        frame.setLocationByPlatform( true );
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> JComboBox-es appear only on a click

because you use them as `CellEditor`, which apper only when you edit cells. If you want to display your column cells as `JComboBox` everytime, you need to use `TableCellRenderer`, [read about that](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#renderer). Here is simple example of `JComboBox` as renderer :

```
import java.awt.Component;

import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.table.TableColumn;

public class TestFrame extends JFrame{

    public TestFrame(){
        init();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    private void init() {
        JTable t = new JTable(3,3);
        TableColumn column = t.getColumnModel().getColumn(2);
        column.setCellRenderer(getRenderer());
        add(new JScrollPane(t));
    }

    private TableCellRenderer getRenderer() {
        return new TableCellRenderer() {

            private JComboBox<String> box = new JComboBox<String>(new String[]{"1","2"});
            @Override
            public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value,
                    boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
                box.setBackground(isSelected ? table.getSelectionBackground() : table.getBackground());
                box.setForeground(isSelected ? table.getSelectionForeground() : table.getForeground());
                return box;
            }
        };
    }

    public static void main(String... s){
        new TestFrame();
    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: The problem is that the content of each JComboBox is different.

Comment: Manage that as you managed different Editors `JComboBox` content

Comment: Please see my update that is based on your code. Now the problem is that selected items of all JComboBox-es are the same. But when I click on JComboBox, I can see the proper dropdown list.

Comment: Seems after filling your comboBox, you need to select value, like next `box.setSelectedItem(value);`

Comment: No,the problem is a bit more tricky. Let's say I should create JTable with 2 rows. The JComboBox of the FIRST row should be populated with employees[0].getQualification() = {"Programmer","Web"}. The JComboBox of the SECOND row should be populated with employees[1].getQualification() = {"Writer","Editor"}. The problem is that in both rows I see "Programmer" as a selected item!!! Only when I click on JComboBox, I see the proper dropdown list.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @alex2410, I cleaned up the code and wrapped it into a ComboTable class which should do the job for you. instantiate ComboTable class with a hashmap of each row values (the demo assumes 2 columns, but you can add more). Note MyMap.of is just a wrapper for java 9 Map.of since I was using Java 8 at that time. same for MyList.of

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ComponentAdapter;
import java.awt.event.ComponentEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.util.EventObject;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.swing.DefaultCellEditor;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.event.CellEditorListener;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellEditor;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer;

import rs.code.utils.MyList;
import rs.code.utils.MyMap;

public class Test extends JFrame
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public ComboTable table = new ComboTable(MyMap.of("Gender", MyList.of("male", "female"), "City", MyList.of("london", "bedord"), "orientation", MyList.of("left", "right")));
    public Test()
    {
        super("EachRow Editor Example");
        JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(table);
        getContentPane().add(scroll, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 120));
        setLocation(150, 100);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Test frame = new Test();
        frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter()
        {
            @Override
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e)
            {
                System.out.println(frame.table.getSelectedValues().toString());
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
    }
}

class ComboTable extends JTable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    protected Map<Integer, ComboCellEditor> editors = new LinkedHashMap<>();

    public ComboTable(Map<String, List<String>> rows)
    {
        setModel(new DefaultTableModel(new String[] {"Attribute", "Value"}, rows.size()));
        setRowHeight(20);
        EachRowEditor rowEditor = new EachRowEditor(this);
        int i = 0;
        for(String key : rows.keySet())
        {
            getModel().setValueAt(key, i, 0);
            editors.put(i++, new ComboCellEditor(createComboBox(rows.get(key))));
        }

        getColumn("Value").setCellEditor(rowEditor);
        getColumn("Value").setCellRenderer(getRenderer());
    }

    public Map<Integer, ComboCellEditor> getEditors()
    {
        return editors;
    }

    public Map<String, String> getSelectedValues()
    {
        Map<String, String> values = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        for(int i=0;i<getModel().getRowCount();i++)
        {
            values.put(getModel().getValueAt(i, 0).toString(), editors.get(i).getComboBox().getSelectedItem().toString());
        }
        return values;
    }

    private JComboBox<String> createComboBox(List<String> elements)
    {
        JComboBox<String> comboBox = new JComboBox<>();
        for (String element : elements)
        {
            comboBox.addItem(element);
        }
        comboBox.setSelectedIndex(0);
        comboBox.addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter()
        {
            @Override
            public void componentShown(ComponentEvent e)
            {
                final JComponent c = (JComponent) e.getSource();
                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
                {
                    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
                    @Override
                    public void run()
                    {
                        c.requestFocus();
                        System.out.println(c);
                        if (c instanceof JComboBox)
                        {
                            System.out.println(((JComboBox) c).getSelectedItem());
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        return comboBox;
    }

    private TableCellRenderer getRenderer()
    {
        return new TableCellRenderer()
        {
            @Override
            public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column)
            {
                editors.get(row).getComboBox().setBackground(isSelected ? table.getSelectionBackground() : table.getBackground());
                editors.get(row).getComboBox().setForeground(isSelected ? table.getSelectionForeground() : table.getForeground());
                return editors.get(row).getComboBox();
            }
        };
    }
}

class ComboCellEditor extends DefaultCellEditor
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private final JComboBox<String> comboBox;

    public ComboCellEditor(JComboBox<String> comboBox)
    {
        super(comboBox);
        this.comboBox = comboBox;
    }

    public JComboBox<String> getComboBox()
    {
        return comboBox;
    }
}

class EachRowEditor implements TableCellEditor
{
    private TableCellEditor editor;
    private final TableCellEditor defaultEditor;
    private final ComboTable table;

    public EachRowEditor(ComboTable table)
    {
        this.table = table;
        defaultEditor = new DefaultCellEditor(new JTextField());

    }

    public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, int row, int column)
    {
        return editor.getTableCellEditorComponent(table, value, isSelected, row, column);
    }

    public Object getCellEditorValue()
    {
        return editor.getCellEditorValue();
    }

    public boolean stopCellEditing()
    {
        return editor.stopCellEditing();
    }

    public void cancelCellEditing()
    {
        editor.cancelCellEditing();
    }

    public boolean isCellEditable(EventObject anEvent)
    {
        selectEditor((MouseEvent) anEvent);
        return editor.isCellEditable(anEvent);
    }

    public void addCellEditorListener(CellEditorListener l)
    {
        editor.addCellEditorListener(l);
    }

    public void removeCellEditorListener(CellEditorListener l)
    {
        editor.removeCellEditorListener(l);
    }

    public boolean shouldSelectCell(EventObject anEvent)
    {
        selectEditor((MouseEvent) anEvent);
        return editor.shouldSelectCell(anEvent);
    }

    protected void selectEditor(MouseEvent e)
    {
        int row;
        if (e == null)
        {
            row = table.getSelectionModel().getAnchorSelectionIndex();
        }
        else
        {
            row = table.rowAtPoint(e.getPoint());
        }
        editor = table.getEditors().get(row);
        if (editor == null)
        {
            editor = defaultEditor;
        }
    }
}
```