# How to have JComboBox as elements in JList?

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox, jlist

I want to create a JList with each element being a JCombo box.

So far i realised that i need to implement my own ListCellRenderer but i do not know how to go about it.

Comment: A JList doesn't support editing. Try using a single column `JTable`. You can specify a JComboBox as an editor for the column. See [Using a ComboBox as an Editor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#combobox)

Comment: I managed to create a JList with CheckBox as elements, and thought someone might have done the same for the JComboBox. Will look into it though, thanks!

Comment: Again, why reinvent the wheel? A JTable supports check boxes as well.

Answer (score 0):

To anyone coming here,
I took the advice of @camickr and implemenented this with `JTable`.

However the linked answer provides the same `JCombBox` for each row.
With that in mind, and deciding to take his advice there is already a solution provided
at [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22605095/jtable-with-different-jcombobox-es-for-each-row).